# Java is not looping the application after rolling the number to initiate the loop

Tags: java

The game is craps, except when I am trying to do is, every time the number 10(`DRAW`) is produced I would like the program to keep rolling. Every time 10 is produced the program closes.

I thought adding the `while` statement would produce the loops i desired but it does not.

````
    private enum Status { CONTINUE, DRAW, WON, LOST };


    private static final int SNAKE_EYES = 2;
    private static final int TREY = 3;
    private static final int SEVEN = 7;
    private static final int YO_LEVEN = 11;
    private static final int BOX_CARS = 12;
    private static final int TENN = 10;

    public static void main (String[] args){

        int myPoint = 0;
        int drawPoint = 10;
        Status gameStatus;

        int sumOfDice = rollDice();



        switch (sumOfDice)
        {
            case TENN:
                gameStatus = Status.DRAW;
                drawPoint = sumOfDice;
                System.out.printf("Point is %d%n", drawPoint);
                break;
            case SEVEN:
            case YO_LEVEN:
                gameStatus = Status.WON;
                break;
            case SNAKE_EYES:
            case TREY:
            case BOX_CARS:
                gameStatus = Status.LOST;
                break;
            default:
                gameStatus = Status.CONTINUE;
                myPoint = sumOfDice;
                System.out.printf("Point is %d%n", myPoint);
                break;


        }

        while (gameStatus == Status.CONTINUE && gameStatus == Status.DRAW)
        {
            sumOfDice = rollDice();

            if (sumOfDice == myPoint)
                gameStatus = Status.WON;        
            else
                if (sumOfDice == SEVEN)
                    gameStatus = Status.LOST;
        }


        if (gameStatus == Status.WON)
            System.out.println("Player wins");
        else
            System.out.println("Player loses");        
    }```

Every time the number 10 is rolled I expect the program to start roll again.
````

Comment: The `gameStatus` can never simultaneously be `CONTINUE` and `DRAW`.  Did you mean `CONTINUE` *or* `DRAW` (`||` operator instead of `&&`)?

Comment: @azurefrog it seems that adding the ```||``` operator instead of the ```&&``` operator fixed the issue. Why is that? If you don't mind me asking. Otherwise, I can google this. :) Thanks!

Comment: I went ahead and googled it. I can see why now. Thank you so much for your help! Thanks!